# Search results to include WordPress Meta Box

Tags: wordpress, search, metadata

I have a bunch of custom meta boxes, I'd like to have the values of these meta boxes added to the search when someone uses my search form. Is it possible to do this?

For example, I have a credit meta box. When someone searches for "Spielberg" I'd like the Jurassic Park page to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following links. Thanks

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35864/how-to-make-search-include-data-from-wp-postmeta

Comment: That second post looks promising, I'll look into it and post back. Thanks!

Comment: @DrewBaker where is the "post back"? Don't make promises you can't keep.